# How do I save a cover image from post's image-set using Pillow in Django

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I have a function that accepts a post object and an image form-set (made with Django's `modelformset_factory`). I expect it to create a cover photo for the post using the first image in the image form-set (instead it points `post.cover_image.path` to the same path). It successfully saves the post images and post cover-image, but the problem is that it also makes the first image in the post's image set blurry as the cover-photo after saving.

```
from PIL import Image as PIL_Image

def handle_uploaded_post_images(post, post_image_formset):
  for index, form in enumerate(post_image_formset.cleaned_data):
    try:
      image = form['image']
      post_image = Images(post=post, image=image)
      post_image.save()

      if index == 0 or not post.cover_image:
      post.cover_image = post_image.image
      post.save()

      cover_image = PIL_Image.open(post.cover_image.path)
      cover_image.thumbnail((480, 480))
      cover_image.save(post.cover_image.path)

    except (KeyError, FileNotFoundError) as e:
      pass
```

I just want to make a cover-photo without affecting the post's images.

Comment: Isn't `cover_image.thumbnail((480, 480))`  cause the blurry cover-image?

Comment: That's correct, but I expect it to only use the pillow thumbnail method on the post's cover image, not on the post's image from where it created the cover image.